# How does one concatenate cell arrays that are part of a cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, concatenation, cell-array

I have a cell array `allData` which is Nx1. Each cell contains a structure with a `names` property (the name is a custom object, but think of it as a cell array of strings if you like). I would like to create a single cell array that contains all of the names. For example, if N=3, so that `allData` is a 3x1 cell array, then the following would accomplish my goal:

```
A = allData{1};
B = allData{2};
C = allData{3};

allNames = [A.names B.names C.names];
```

The problem with this approach is that N is large and changes depending on the input, so I'm hoping that there is a clever way to do this using `cellfun`, but everything that I've tried fails (e.g. it doesn't work to do `allNames = [cellfun(@(x) {x.names}, allData)];`).

**UPDATE:** Thanks to the suggested solutions, I can get everything into one cell array where each cell contains a cell array. My goal here is to concatenate these. More or less, what I have is:

```
{A.names B.names C.names}
```

and what I want and cannot seem to get is

```
{A.names{1} A.names{2} ... A.names{end} B.names{1} ... B.names{end} ...}
```

**SOLUTION**:
I needed pieces of each answer below, so here's the solution that worked for me:

from [Andrew Lazarus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717898/andrew-lazarus):

`allNames = arrayfun(@(x) x.name, [allData{:}], 'UniformOutput', false);`

then, from [gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice):

`allNames = vertcat(allNames{:});`

Thanks to both!!

Comment: Are the structures scalar (i.e. 1-by-1), or can they be structure *arrays*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few more details about your cell contents that would be needed for a more general solution, but if the `names` property always returns a cell array of strings, and if your structures are all scalars (i.e. 1-by-1 structure arrays), then the following solution using [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html), [CHAR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/char.html), and [CELLSTR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellstr.html) will give you an N-by-1 cell array of strings `allNames` containing all of your names:

```
allNames = cellfun(@(x) {char(x.names)},allData);
allNames = cellstr(char(allNames{:}));
```

And here's an example where `allData` contains three different structures:

```
>> allData{1} = struct('names',{{'hello'}},'junk',1:3);
>> allData{2} = struct('names',{{'hi' 'yo' 'hey' 'whassup'}});
>> allData{3} = struct('names',{{'howdy';'aloha'}},'junk',4);
>> allNames = cellfun(@(x) {char(x.names)},allData);
>> allNames = cellstr(char(allNames{:}))

allNames = 

    'hello'
    'hi'
    'yo'
    'hey'
    'whassup'
    'howdy'
    'aloha'
```

**EDIT:**

Generalizing to the case where the `names` property returns a cell array of *objects*, not necessarily strings, you can try this solution which [reshapes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) each cell array into an M-by-1 cell array, then [vertically concatenates](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/vertcat.html) all of them into an N-by-1 cell array of objects:

```
allNames = cellfun(@(x) {reshape(x.names,[],1)},allData);
allNames = vertcat(allNames{:});
```

Or, if you would rather end up with a 1-by-N cell array of objects, you can do this:

```
allNames = cellfun(@(x) {reshape(x.names,1,[])},allData);
allNames = [allNames{:}];
```

Comment: This is great if they are cell arrays of strings, but sadly I misled you. They are cell arrays of custom objects. Still, I may be able to get some mileage out of this approach. Thanks!

Comment: @PengOne: The moral of the story being "remember to provide sample data in your question".

Comment: @Richie Cotton: The object is defined over several files and many, many lines, so it only clouds the question which at the heart is simple: How can I concatenate cell arrays that themselves are cells in a cell array?

Comment: @PengOne: I've updated my answer to deal more generally with *objects* as opposed to strings.

Comment: JessumCrow! The `vertcat` function worked (once I transposed correctly)! Thanks for this. I did not need to reshape for my example, but please leave it in your solution in case someone else beats his head against the wall on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 allNames = arrayfun(@(x) x.name, [allData{:}], 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Omit the UniformOutput vararg for straight concatenation. This gives a cell output.

Comment: The operation `[allData{:}]` will only work if the elements of the cell array can be horizontally concatenated into a structure array, which would mean there was no real reason to use a cell array in the first place.

Comment: @PengOne: note the [brackets]. But I'll try for a more generic solution.

Comment: Tried this... result is a 1x3 cell array, each cell containing one of the cell arrays that I truly wish would just find a way to concatenate themselves!

Comment: @PengOne, Not quite sure what you mean, but a possibility: By changing UniformOutput to true, you get array output. That is the default anyway. You may need to transpose the output to get a concatenated single string.